# Drupal 7 Single Sign On Issue

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, single-sign-on, drupal-modules

** Single Sign On Issue in Drupal 7**

Can Drupal 7 experts guide me to fix the single sign on issuse with drupal 7 site

We're building a portal www.rithanya.com which will bring multiple sub domains namely

- a.rithanya.com
- b.rithanya.com
- c.rithanya.com

etc... Sub domains will increase as per our CTO's guidance. Each domain as its own database but it share single drupal 7 code base.

We wanted to achieve single sign-on for users to go around all these sites. Till now we've tried out SSO module for this but I am not able to achieve the output and has security issues.

It Looks like this could be achieved within setting.php itselves without no modules, which we learned through these links & more.

- http://www.seedem.co/en/blog/drupal-single-sign-easy-way
- http://www.drupixels.com/blog/single-sign-drupal-7

and tried the same using configuring setting.php file. we were able to achieve the output of single sign on but it affects the UI/theme of the site. Some major/minor tweeks would be required it seems. 
Anyone has achieved it before ?

Can anyone suggest any way for it which will solve this issuse.

Comment: You have to create a custom module to handle sign in , hook all ways to access to sign in and handle it by condition on domain

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the ldap module https://www.drupal.org/project/ldap . It's very easy to setup especially for sub-domains. The bakery single sign on may be a good solution for you but it's less used nowadays https://www.drupal.org/project/bakery